# Keyboard Shortcut to Run Macro in Excel for Mac

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, macros

Basically the title says it all. In the editor in Excel on Windows, all you have to do to run a macro is press F5. What is the keyboard shortcut to do this on a Mac?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the default is **option-F8** to open the macro window.

You can set it to F5 if you would like via Tools->Customize Keyboard… menu. Note that F5 is currently set to the "Go To" dialog box.

Comment: This is true for Excel 2011.  The customize keyboard feature was removed from Excel 2016.  You may want to update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Office 365 for Mac, and it is still true. With soft function keys default to other functions, the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key needs to be pressed.

Press the below combination to bring up the Macro window.
<kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>F8</kbd>